# WP Minify and optimizing CSS Delivery

Tags: html, css, wordpress, asynchronous, google-pagespeed

I am trying to boost my google page speed score and one of the only issues i have left is that it says that i need to Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/themes/gather/style.css

So i have wp minify sorting out a lot of the page speed tasks so don't want to disable that but how do you defer or asynchronously this load blocking plugin?

Thanks